# Intellij idea failing to push to github

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, push, jetbrains-ide

There're variations of this question on the internet, I've tried following the other questions answers but to no avail.

The problem is basically whenever I try to push my changes to the repository at github I get the following error:
"Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

My ssh keys are ~/.ssh/github_rsa and github_rsa.pub.
I have set a passphrase as well as a .bashrc file @ %userprofile%:

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
fi

unset env
```

I also changed Intellij settings of ssh client to Native.
Every operation works fine in git bash but no in Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I finally was able to fix this tedious error.
What you have to do is create an ssh config in ~/.ssh/config
like so:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

This is because Intellij expect the key files to be id_rsa by default so we need to guide it a bit.
After that I switched back my ssh client in the settings from Native back to built-in, and voila ! :)